# Where does SQL Server LocalDB store master DB and list of databases?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

Where in the file system does SQL Server LocalDB store its system databases, like `master` or `tempdb`?

Connecting to LocalDB using SSMS, all the LocalDB databases appear in Object Explorer. So there must be a `master` database somewhere on the hard drive.

Comment: Look under Databases > System Databases in Object Explorer

Comment: Paron me for being unclear in my question. I'm looking for the file storage location on disk. I updated my question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you also want to know where the database files are then using SSMS right click on a database and choose properties and then go to files. You may also find the following query helpful.

```
SELECT db_name(database_id) as DatabaseName, name,type_desc, physical_name
FROM sys.master_files
```